# APIs for selecting countries and regions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

[image: This is my requirement]

Users have to choose the country depending on the requirements. There are suggestions for "enter your location" and the locations are under this country. Mobile code is automatically selected based on that country. This is my requirement. I did the Country Codes Choice field manually and used the django-phonenumber-field package for the phone number field, but I can't reach the requirement.
Are there any APIs for location, countries and mobile code? Can someone help me.?

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate this library using a custom template tag:

https://pypi.org/project/phone-iso3166/